# Problems with Toplevel Widget and Portscanner

Tags: python, multithreading, widget, tkinter

```
def PortScanWin():

win2 = Toplevel()
win2.title("PortScan")
win2.wm_maxsize(width='190',height='370')
win2.wm_minsize(width='190',height='370')

def go():
    global app
    result.delete(1.0,END)
    app=scan()
    app.start() 

def stop():
    app.flag='stop'

def clear():
    host_e.delete(0,END)
    start_port_e.delete(0,END)
    end_port_e.delete(0,END)
    result.delete(1.0,END)

class scan(threading.Thread):
    def _init_(self):
        threading.thread._init_(self)
    def run(self):
        self.host=host_e.get() 
        self.start_port=int(start_port_e.get())
        self.end_port=int(end_port_e.get())
        self.open_counter=0
        self.flag='scan'       
        start.config(text="Stop",command=stop)
        win2.update()
        result.insert(END,"Scanning "+str(self.host)+"...\n\n")
        win2.update()
        while self.start_port<=self.end_port and self.flag=='scan':
            self.sk=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.sk.settimeout(0.01) 
            try:
                self.sk.connect((self.host,self.start_port))
            except:
                pass 
            else:
                result.insert(END,str(self.start_port)+"\n")
                win2.update()
                self.open_counter=self.open_counter+1
                self.sk.close()
            self.start_port=self.start_port+1
        if self.flag=='scan':    
            result.insert(END,"\nDone !!\nFound "+str(self.open_counter)+" opened ports")
            win2.update()
            start.config(text="Scan",command=go)
            win2.update()
        elif self.flag=='stop':
            result.insert(END,"\n Scan stopped.")
            start.config(text="Scan",command=go)
            win2.update()

Label(win2,text="Host: ").grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="w")
host_e=Entry(win2)
host_e.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky="WE")
Label(win2,text="Start port: ").grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="w")
start_port_e=Entry(win2)
start_port_e.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky="WE")
Label(win2,text="End port: ").grid(row=3,column=1,sticky="w")
end_port_e=Entry(win2)
end_port_e.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky="WE")
start=Button(win2,text="Scan",command=go)
start.grid(row=5,columnspan=3,sticky="WE")
clear=Button(win2,text="Clear",command=clear)
clear.grid(row=6,columnspan=3,sticky="WE")
result=Text(win2,width=20,height=20)
result.grid(row=7,columnspan=3,sticky="WENS")
```

The portscanner is being run in a child window, but some how it doesnt work, When I click "Scan" I get "Scanning..None" and it doesnt do anything, Any help will be highly appreciated, Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to trust the feedback you get. In your case the code is printing "Scanning... None". So, obviously something is "None" when it (presumably) should be something else. Figure out why `self.host` is None and you'll likely solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to your question, but you may like to check out Scapy. Scapy lets you build your own packets and read raw data from a network interface. Both are obviously very helpful in writing a port scanner. So, depending on what you need, you may wish to replace your port-scanner with one written in Scapy.

More information at: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/